# the runtime complexity of the product nxn Matrix time n Vector

Tags: time-complexity

If I have  nxn matrixes A and vector (b1, b2, .., bn). What is the runtime complexity of A.v?
someone told me O(n^2) but I do not understand the reason for this runtime?

```
since A*v =

a11*b1+ a12*b2+.....+a1n*bn,

a21*b1+ a22*b2+.....+a2n*bn,

.

.

.

.an1*b1+ an2*b2+.....+ann*bn
```

for the first line we need O(n), for the second O(n), ..., for the last O(n)
also total run time is O(n).

Comment: You do O(n) work n times, and end up with a total of O(n)?

Comment: Yes it is. Look here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations.; It is in your case O(1*n*n) = O(n^2)

Comment: @ScottHunter: also because I have n entires in the vector then I have n.n = n^2

Comment: It depends if n represent the input vector or the number of elements in the matrix. For a vector of size 2 you make 4 ops for size 4 you make 16 ops. But it also mean a matrix of size 2*2 => 4 ops and 4*4 => 16 ops

Comment: @user43968: The question clearly states the matrix is nxn.

Comment: @MrAsker: You state there are n^2 elements in the matrix, and every one of them has to be multiplied by something; how then do you come up with "total run time is O(n)"?

Comment: @ScottHunter: Ok I got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Let A,B,C are n*m,m*k and n*k matrices respectively where C=A*B. In general cases for compute C we have C_{i,j}=∑∑∑َA_{i,k}*B_{k,j} so time complexity for matrices multiplication is O(n*m*k) and this show with O(n^3). Also, since your B is a vector, complexity is O(n^2).